# Passing 2D double array from C# to C++ function

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I have a function in a Managed class in c++. Let's call this function CopyDoubles. This function only receives two arrays as arguments.

```
double ManagedClass::CopyDoubles(double acopy[][3], double bcopy[][3]){
    //code
}
```

From C#, I can access this function, however, I can't pass it the arguments correctly. I tried this.

```
double [,] a = new double[128,3];
double [,] b = new double[128,3];

double result = Managed.CopyDoubles(a,b);
```

But it does not work. What am I missing? The function will not take a and b as arguments as they are.

Answer (score 0):

The class name `Managed` used for C++ functions  confuses me. Maybe you mean C++/CLI?

You should allocate normal handles to your arrays. Then you can get a stable pointers to your arrays that you can pass to your C++ method. Pinning an object prevents the garbage collector from moving it around in memory.

```
GCHandle pinnedA = GCHandle.Alloc(a, GCHandleType.Pinned);
GCHandle pinnedB = GCHandle.Alloc(b, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointerA = pinnedA.AddrOfPinnedObject();  
IntPtr pointerB = pinnedA.AddrOfPinnedObject();

double result = Managed.CopyDoubles(pointerA, pointerB);

pinnedA.Free();
pinnedB.Free();
```

If you are allowed to used unsafe code in your project, you can use the fixed context:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (double* pA = a) fixed (double* pB = b)
    {
         double result = Managed.CopyDoubles(pA, pB);
    }
}
```